# Is it possible to run a string injection attack on a redis query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm building a little token-based authentication library for my (rails based) api server which uses redis to store generated auth tokens. The line I'm worried about is: `user_id = $redis.get("auth:#{token}")`, where token is what's passed in to authenticate_or_request_with_http_token.

If this were SQL, that'd be a huge red flag - string interpolated SQL queries are pretty insecure. As far as I can tell, however, doing string interpolation on a redis key query isn't insecure.

My source for the above claim is the redis documentation here: http://redis.io/topics/security (under the *string escaping and nosql injection* header), but I wanted to make sure that this is the case before I get a Bobby Tables attack.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The documentation you are pointing to is quite explicit:

> The Redis protocol has no concept of string escaping, so injection is impossible under normal circumstances using a normal client library. The protocol uses prefixed-length strings and is completely binary safe.

Comment: Not sure that really applies: if the value of the string would be smth like `asd"asd` it might lead to e.g. `set key "asd"asd"` which means the users input broke out of the value.

Comment: @user1347198 What do you base that "might" on? Did you find a hint in the docs, read the source code, or do any form of testing? Because simply assuming a system will do something without building intuition for that system first is meaningless.

Answer (score 18):

There is a small attack vector for these kinds of string injections. While the redis documentation is clear about the difficulty of executing multiple commands on the database, it does not mention that the key separator (':' in your example) usually needs to be escaped when used as the part of a key.

I have seen a redis database using these keys:

- `oauth_token:123456` (which contained a hash of OAuth token parameters) and
- `oauth_token:123456:is_temp` (which contained a boolean property to indicate whether the OAuth token is a temporary token)

Trusting the user input without escaping might result in `GET oauth_token:#{token}` accidentally ending up as `GET oauth_token:123456:is_temp` (when token has been set to `123456:is_temp` by the user).

So I highly recommend to properly escape colons from potential user input to make sure your key paths cannot be tricked like this.

**NOTE:** Someone recommended to fix the example above by using `oauth_token:123456` and `oauth_token:is_temp:123456`, but that is flawed (for the user-provided token `is_temp:123456`). The correct solution to that problem (without escaping) would be to use keys `oauth_token:info:123456` and `oauth_token:is_temp:123456` to make sure these keys cannot overlap whatever the user-provided input was (or simply escape colons).

Comment: Another solution would be to ensure that your cache keys never end in user-tainted data.

Comment: I found this answer to be extremely useful. Thanks @herzi!

Answer (score 5):

Basically Redis is immune from escaping issues when the input string is used verbatim. For example:

```
SET mykey <some-attacker-chosen-data>
```

However Redis is not immune from issues arising by using non validate input in the context of string *interpolation*, as showed by Sven Herzberg. In order to turn the Sven example into a safe one, it is possible to just use an Hash, and avoid reverting to interpolation. Otherwise either use not common prefixes to use in conjunction with keys interpolation, or use some basic form of sanity check on the input, which is, filtering away the separator used, or better, validate that the input is actually a number (in the specific example).

So while Redis does not suffer from the typical injection attacks of SQL, when used untrusted input in the context of a string interpolation used to create key names, or even worse, Lua scripts, some care should be taken.